# Animating Dynamic Height Properly in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page that has a wizard. The wizard has three steps in it.

When a user goes from step 1 to step 2, step 2 pushes the content in step 1 down below it. When a user goes from step 2 to step 3, the content flips over to show the content in step 3, effectively hiding the content in step 1 and 2. I have this working as shown in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/phAIa306aR). The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#eee;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flip-container">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <div class="step-2-default" id="step2" style="overflow-x:hidden; padding:0.0rem 1.0rem;">
            <label>Step 2</label>
            <p>These are the details of the second step</p>
            <button id="nextButton2">next</button>        
          </div>

          <div class="step-1-default" id="step1">
            <label>Step 1</label>
            <p>These are the details of the first step</p>
            <button id="nextButton1">next</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="back">
          <div id="step3">
            <label>Step 3</label>
            <p>Thank you for using this wizard</p>
          </div>                                
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the first line, notice that the `background-color` is set to `eee`. That is not appearing. The reason it is not appearing is because the `div` height is 0. I want this div to size itself based on the height of the `div` with the class front. In other words, the div will never be shorter than the `div` with the class front. However, when step 2 is revealed, the height of this div will grow. For that reason, it needs to be dynamic.

How can I do this? It's driving me NUTS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the height of `.front` and `.back` to 100%. But 100% of what? You need to be more specific about the height, e.g. use pixels, or set the height to auto. The second option is better if you will have dynamic content.

```
.front, .back {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/TRultgcBbU)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I looked at the demo and it didn't match my explanation of the problem. I've since updated the bootply to hopefully make it more clear. The outer most container is the element that I need to grow. At this time, it sees its internal content as having a height of 0.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Your problem is that you once you set .front and .back to position:absolute, they are removed from the flow of the page and the parent container will collapse.

Comment: @user687554 Here's one way ---> http://www.bootply.com/f637zchFac# -- You can position absolute the last step - so it's essentially covering the previous 2 steps.